# How to modify parent class' variables from a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, parent

I'm pretty sure I know why this isn't working but how do I make this work?
Ok so I have a parent class that has a bunch of virtual functions and 1 non virtual function

Ex:

```
class Parent
{
private: 
    int variable;
public:
    virtual void firstfunction(); 
    virtual void secondfunction(); 
    void nonvirtualfunction();
};

Parent::nonvirtualfunction()
{
    variable = 5;
}
```

I have a child class that inherits from the parent class

```
class Child : public Parent
{
    void firstfunction();
    void secondfunction();
}

Child::secondfunction()
{
    Parent::nonvirtualfunction();
}
```

When I call nonvirtualfunction inside my child class it doesn't change the value inside the parent class. How do I make it so that I can change the parent class' variables inside the child class?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make any sense.  Your parent has only an instance variable not a class variable.

Comment: Please show a complete example that demonstrates your problem. I'm thinking there's a mis-understanding somewhere in how you use these classes.

Answer (score 3):

Your example code does work: http://ideone.com/zRvp93

The only major problems in your example are that `Child`'s member functions are private and `Parent::nonvirtualfunction` and `Child::secondfunction` are missing their return types.